# What should happen when an if clause has an undefined variable

Tags: php

I'm working with a legacy code base, and see this:

```
public static function blah($formData = array()) {
  $x = null;
  $y = null;

  if ($formData['x'] || $formData['y']) {
    $x = $formData['x'];

    if ($formData['y'])
      $y = $formData['y'];

    return $x - $y;
  }

  //does some other stuff with x/y and then returns the result 
}
```

Obviously, this code is unbearably bad, but I'm not entirely sure what the intended effect should be. The reason I found this problem is because I ran the code in an environment where Strict Checking is on, and the `if` clause caused the function to die because neither `x` nor `y` is defined in at least some instances of this function being called.

**Without strict checking on, is an if block skipped should one of the variables in the clause not be defined?**

Comment: No that would only be skipped if both conditions aren't met. You're just getting a notice that `$formData` doesn't have a specific key, but if one of the conditions were satisfied, the `if` would still execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php, undefined is treated as `FALSE` for purposes of `if` tests (though they obviously recommend against using this).

Answer (score 0):

```
case defined `$formData['x']` only -- function return `$formData['x']`
case defined `$formData['y']` only -- function return `-$formData['y']`
case defined `$formData['x']` and `$formData['y']` -- function return `$formData['x']-$formData['y']`
case all undefined -- your function will continue
```

P.S. undefined variable casts as NULL, NULL in arithmetic operators casts as 0.